# Schduling theory with weekends and holidays

Tags: scheduling

My wife has a small workshop where she fixes dolls. 
She works alone without any external help.
She has N orders from her clients, she estimates each order and she has deadline for each order.
She asks me to make a program which will create a schedule for her.
She wants to minimize a number of overdues. Also the program should take care of weekends and holidays.

It seems to be 1||SUM(Uj) problem where Uj is an order...
And there is Moore's algorithm for solving this. 
https://web-static.stern.nyu.edu/om/faculty/pinedo/scheduling/shakhlevich/handout04.pdf
"Minimising number of late jobs" part is exactly about this.
But if we have to take holydays into account then
Orders:
A: estimate 1, deadline 3
B: estimate 2, deadline 2
C: estimate 3, deadline 5

c - current day, work day also
w - work day
h - holyday
c h h w w w

Moore's algorithm will position orders like this: B, A, C and all of them will overdue
But there is A, B, C and only B and C are overdue.
Hence Moore's algorithm does not work if holydays and weekends need to be taken into account.

Does anyone know how to approach such a problem?

Comment: One generic "hammer" that can be used to solve many such problems is to formulate it as an instance of integer linear programming, and use an ILP solver.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by fixing units of measurement.
Estimates are counted in "work days", but deadlines are "calendar days"
So, if we take a count of calendar days before a deadline and subtract a count of holydays and other non working days then we will have a deadline in "working days" and Moore's algorithm works fine now.
We can get calendar dates by a similar (but vice-versa) transformation.